# Why won't the media query activate when I make the browser window smaller?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am sorry to ask a simple question but I am trying to use a different style sheet when the window gets smaller or a mobile device is used. Nothing happens when I shrink the browser window smaller. Here is the media query.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
     media="screen and (max-device-width:500px)"
     href="2ndCss.css" />
```

Can someone explain why it's not doing anything? I have tried making the max-device width smaller and I have tried setting it to max-width instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take careful note of what you have in your media attribute, you will notice that you are using `max-device-width`. What that means is that the physical device must have a screen size of `500px` or less for the media query to kick in. Resizing your browser doesn't change the physical size of your screen.

You may be better served using `max-width` instead of `max-device-width`.

Comment: Is there a way I can do both?

Comment: @redelman431 Yes, there is. Use the following: `screen and (max-width: 500px) and (max-device-width: 500px)`. See here for more information: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#width